# Check which constructor has been called

Tags: haskell

How do I check if a constructor has been called or not?

I have created this data for training purposes:

The reason I did it that way is that I wanted to have constructors for each imaginable nesting.

```hs
data Testdatatype a = TestA String [Testdatatype a]
           | TestB String  (Testdatatype a) (Testdatatype a)
           | TestC String (Testdatatype a)
           | TestD String
           | TestE a
           deriving Eq
```

Now I want to check if TestD has been called.

So I did:

```hs
gotCalledOnce :: Testdatatype a -> Bool
gotCalledOnce (TestD _) = True
gotCalledOnce _ = False
```

```hs
gotCalledInGeneral :: Testdatatype a -> Bool
gotCalledInGeneral a = fmap (gotCalledOnce) a
```

It is not working, and I do not understand the reason why.

I want to have it checked if it occurs even if the Data Constructor has been called in the middle of the expression and not in the very beginning.

Comment: `fmap` maps a `Testdatatype a` to a `Testdatatype b`, not to a `Bool`. In this case, the `fmap gotCalledOnce a` thus has type `Testdatatype (Testdatatype a) -> Testdatatype Bool`. Here the `Testdatatype` is not an instance of `Functor`, hence `fmap` can not work on a `Testdatatype`.

Comment: I recommend you get away from the picture that functions are “called”. This doesn't make much sense for Haskell functions in general, and constructors in particular.

Comment: What is `gotCalledOnce a = (TestD _) = True` supposed to mean? Perhaps you wanted to write `gotCalledOnce (TestD _) = True`? And what difference you expect to have between `gotCalledOnce` and `gotCalledInGeneral`? They have the same type, what do you expect them to do differently?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If mapping is not the way to solve my problem, which tool I should consider?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes,  the 'a' is an accident. I will edit my post. You are absolutely right. The difference and why I made both is: The first should just check if a constructor got called (even tho leftaroundabout said I shouldnt use the word, I do not know how to describe it better). And I made to it check it for the entire Data structure. I thought thats the purpose of mapping.  Applying a function to all the structure.

Comment: In the end I just want to have:

Example1: TestC "hello" TestD "hallo" = True
Example2: TestC "hello" TestE 5 = False

because in Example2 there is no constructor TestD -> False, else True.

Comment: `TestC "hello" TestD "hallo"` What kind of object is this? "the entire Data structure" What *is* the entire data structure?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. TestC "hello" TestD "hallo" its an object of the data type Testdatatype if im not mistaken.

Comment: You are. You probably wanted `TestC "hello" (TestD "hallo")`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work for two reasons.

1. `fmap` does not know how to traverse your data structure because you did not define a `Functor` instance for it.
2. Even if you define a `Functor` instance for it, it will not help because `fmap` does not combine branches of the data structure. You probably want `True` if *any* of e.g. `TestA String [Testdatatype a]` contains `TestD`, but `fmap` has no idea what *any* means. It transforms `Testdatatype a` to `Testdatatype b`, that is, applies a function to whatever branch of your data structure contains an `a`, making it contain a `b` instead. Different applications of the function are completely independent. You can make `b` be `Bool` if you want, but `Testdatatype Bool` is very different from `Bool`.

The most straightforward way to achieve what you want is to traverse your data structure manually.

```
 gotCalledInGeneral :: Testdatatype a -> Bool
 gotCalledInGeneral (TestA _ ts) = any gotCalledInGeneral ts
 gotCalledInGeneral (TestB _ t1 t2) = gotCalledInGeneral t1 || gotCalledInGeneral t2
 gotCalledInGeneral (TestC _ t) = gotCalledInGeneral t
 gotCalledInGeneral (TestD _) = True
 gotCalledInGeneral (TestE _) = False
```

Note how the results are or-ed together in the top two branches.